# Zuul filter requests

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

I am using [Zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul) as reverse proxy deployed as a service using Spring Boot. And I have a configuration like:

```
zuul:
    routes:
       home:
          path: /**
          url: localhost:8080
```

But I want to use the /routes,/info,/health endpoints of the zuul server. Also I want add some endpoints to the zuul server. The problem is that I lost those endpoints because all requests are routed to localhost:8080.

Comment: If you set `management.port=8081`, then you can access the actuator endpoints on a different port.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ignoredPatterns in the latest version of ZUUL can help prevent reaching the /** mapping:

```
zuul:  
  ignoredPatterns: "/routes/**,/info/**,/custom/**"
```